# commutator of a bounded linear operator on hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H=\ell^2$ be a Hilbert space with basis $\{\eta_i\}$.
Let $X= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i}\langle\cdot,\eta_i\rangle\eta_{i+1}$ and $T=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \langle\cdot,\eta_{i+1}\rangle\eta_{i}$. The question is whether there is a compact operator $K\in K(H)$ such that $$(T-K)X =X(T-K). $$

My idea is, $X$ is generated by right shift operator, so, $X$ only commutes with  the convolution operators. But $T$ is left shift operator, and $K$ is compact, it looks like that $T-K$ could not be the convolution operator of right shift operator. But I don't know how to prove it clearly.

Comment: @ThomasRot of course, since K is compact, T is bounded, then TK-KT is compact.

Comment: @ThomasRot  Check?what？  TK is compact, KT is compact, then of course TK-KT is compact...

Comment: @ThomasRot Well。。。 X is also compact, so the necessary condition is satisfied but what about the sufficiency...actually, I want to show to there is no such a $K$

Comment: @ThomasRot never mind, hope to discuss with u when u feel better